# How to find "complicated" URLs in a text file

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm using the following regex to find URLs in a text file:

```
/http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+/
```

It outputs the following:

```
    http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds117.0/.
    http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds111.1/.
    http://www.discover-earth.org/index.html).
    http://community.eosdis.nasa.gov/measures/).
```

Ideally they would print out this:

```
    http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds117.0/
    http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds111.1/
    http://www.discover-earth.org/index.html
    http://community.eosdis.nasa.gov/measures/
```

Any ideas on how I should tweak my regex?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE - Example of the text would be:

```
    this is a test http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds117.0/. and I want this to                 be copied over http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds111.1/. http://www.discover-earth.org/index.html). http://community.eosdis.nasa.gov/measures/).
```

Comment: `https?` is the same as `http[s]?`. Combine all your character classes instead of using `|`: `[$\w@.&+!*(),-]` and place the `-` at the end so it doesn't create a range. You can also replace `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w`. Use `{2}` instead of specifying `[0-9a-fA-F]` twice. You don't need to escape `(` or `)` inside a character class. Making those small changes yields `https?://(?:[$\w@.&+!*(),-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+`

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Would you mind clarify what you need? Is the regex you provided not working? Are you just asking for tips on how to make it better? Maybe you just need a regular expression to parse a URL? (For the latter, then a quick search on google should provide you an answer).

Comment: Also, @ctwheels, you should probably escape your forward slashes, and the you are not allowing for recurring sub directories.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman that's a problem with the original regex. `$-_` creates a range, the user should instead add `/` to the character class. The forward slashes do not need to be escaped. They're not special characters in python regex.

Comment: @ctwheels Woups. Didn't see the python-tag :)

Comment: @ctwheels I thought that was it at first, but it seems to only give me the base url. I need all the extensions. So what you gave me yields: 

        http://rda.ucar.edu
        http://rda.ucar.edu
        http://www.discover-earth.org
        http://community.eosdis.nasa.gov

Sorry for poor formatting, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will trim your output containing trail characters, `) .`

```
import re
regx= re.compile(r'(?m)[\.\)]+$')
print(regx.sub('', your_output))
```

And this regex seems workable to extract `URL` from your original sample text.

```
https?:[\S]*\/(?:\w+(?:\.\w+)?)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/25/),,, ( edited from `https?:[\S]*\/`)

Python script may be something like this

```
ss=""" this is a test http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds117.0/. and I want this to                 be copied over http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds111.1/. http://www.discover-earth.org/index.html). http://community.eosdis.nasa.gov/measures/). """

regx= re.compile(r'https?:[\S]*\/(?:\w+(?:\.\w+)?)?')
for m in regx.findall(ss):
    print(m)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not catch the full urls. "http://www.discover-earth.org/index.html" is only caught up to "http://www.discover-earth.org/"

Comment: Thanks for reponse. Sorry, I missed that point. I edited the regex now, please try it again. Thank you:-)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much!

Comment: Any way we can add to it to search for ftp/ftps links as well? I tried editing it, but wasn't having much luck

Comment: If so, then you can try this regex. `(?:ht|f)tps?:[\S]*\/(?:\w+(?:\.\w+)?)?`  https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/27/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So for the urls you have here:
https://regex101.com/r/uSlkcQ/4

Pattern explanation:

Protocols (e.g. `https://`)

```
^[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)
```

Look for recurring `.[-;:&=+\$,\w]+`-class (www.sub.domain.com)

```
(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+`
```

Look for recurring `/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+` (/some.path/to/somewhere)

```
(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+
```

Now, for your special case: ensure that the last character is not a dot or a parenthesis, using negative lookahead

```
(?!\.|\)).
```

The full pattern is then

```
^[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).
```

Comment: With this, it still doesn't find anything:

^[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).

Comment: You lack a `\)` in your code. Try copy-paste from my answer or from the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uSlkcQ/4) example.

Comment: The end there should be `(?!\.|\))` and _not_ `(?!\.|))`

Comment: ^[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).

This doesn't work :(

Comment: No, it does not. You are lacking a backslash! Use this exact one:
`^([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).)`

Comment: It still does not work - this is the full line:

re.findall('^([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).)', des)

"des" is just the text file read in.

Comment: You are STILL not using the backaslash I've been adding since 5 comments ago. Do the ACTUAL copy paste for what I input below here in this comment!! (I'm not angry, I just really want you to read :) ) 

`re.findall(r'^([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).)', des)`

Comment: Haha I promise I am copying/pasting directly!

Comment: This is exactly what I put in:

re.findall(r'^([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).)', des)

Comment: Argh. Are you just pulling my leg or something? Do you not see that what you say you are using has `(?!\.|)).` at the end, but the one on the site, in my answer and in my comments have 

    ---->` `(?!\.|\)).`  `<----

at the end. There is a backslash difference! See if you can spot the backslash that I am using and you are not. I have to go to bed now. I'll check back tomorrow. Good luck :)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just super inept.

Comment: Haha, don't worry about it. But did you spot it?? If not: Just read! Just find the backslash and all will be good (provided that your code works though). Good night :)

Comment: ... then remove the caret(aka hat), like this:
`re.findall(r'([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+\.?)+(?:\/[\-;:&=\+\$,\w\.]+)+(?!\.|\)).)', des)`

Comment: This is the output I get: ['http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds117.0/. ', 'http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds111.1/. ', 'http://www.discover-earth.org/index.html', 'http://community.eosdis.nasa.gov/measures/']

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to improve or change in your existing regex to allow this to work:

- `http[s]?` can be changed to `https?`. They're identical. No use putting `s` in its own character class
- `[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]` You can shorten this entire thing and combine character classes instead of using `|` between them. This not only improves performance, but also allows you to combine certain ranges into existing character class tokens. Simplifying this, we get `[a-zA-Z0-9$-_@.&+!*\(\),]`

  - We can go one step further: `a-zA-Z0-9_` is the same as `\w`. So we can replace those in the character class to get `[\w$-@.&+!*\(\),]`
  - In the original regex we have `$-_`. This creates a range so it actually inclues everything between `$` and `_` on the ASCII table. This will cause unwanted characters to be matched: `$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`. There are a few options to fix this:

    - `[-\w$@.&+!*\(\),]` Place `-` at the start of the character class
    - `[\w$@.&+!*\(\),-]` Place `-` at the end of the character class
    - `[\w$\-@.&+!*\(\),]` Escape `-` such that you have `\-` instead
  - You don't need to escape `(` and `)` in the character class: `[\w$@.&+!*(),-]`
- `[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]` You don't need to specify `[0-9a-fA-F]` twice. Just use a quantifier like so: `[0-9a-fA-F]{2}`
- `(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])` The non-capture group isn't actually needed here, so we can drop it (it adds another step that the regex engine needs to perform, which is unnecessary)

So the result of just simplifying your existing regex is the following:

```
https?://(?:[$\w@.&+!*(),-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+
```

Now you'll notice it doesn't match `/` so we need to add that to the character class. Your regex was matching this originally because it has an improper range `$-_`.

```
https?://(?:[$\w@.&+!*(),/-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+
```

Unfortunately, even with this change, it'll still match `).` at the end. That's because your regex isn't told to stop matching after `/`. Even implementing this will now cause it to not match file names like `index.html`. So a better solution is needed. If you give me a couple of days, I'm working on a fully functional RFC-compliant regex that matches URLs. I figured, in the meantime, I would at least explain why your regex isn't working as you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses. A coworker ended up helping me with it. Here is the solution:

`des_links = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', des)
for i in des_links:
   tmps = "/".join(i.split('/')[0:-1])
   print(tmps)`